# ActiveForm is Null, can't Activate it

Tags: c#, forms, google-maps

I'm developing an application with 2 components:

1. A speech recognizer that prints stuff on the console;
2. A form with google maps (with GMap.NET dll).

Sometimes, the speech recognizer just stops, other times the google maps interaction does nothing. When any of this happens, the only solution is to re-run the program. The stopping seems random as sometimes I can do several commands before any of it starts to ignore me.
I've found that I need to Invoke the form as the creator of the google maps interaction in order to interact with the maps, however, sometimes System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm returns null and I cannot Invoke it. I think this is the issue that causes all the problems I've encountered.

Is there any workaround or tips?
Many thanks in advance.

```
  if (System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Application.OpenForms.ToString());
            //System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.Activate();
            Console.WriteLine("Active form is null");
        }
        else if (System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            CallBack d = new CallBack(run);
            System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { obj });
        }
```

Comment: Put some code please

Comment: Edited to add the portion of code. That "Active form is null" happens when the map fails to respond, even though the speech recognizer is working (and printing stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use ActiveForm to communicate with your form. In case only one instance of each form will be opened, you can keep a static reference to the form like this:

```
class MyForm
{
    public MyForm
    {
        Current = this;
    }
    public static MyForm Current {get; private set;}
}
```

Now you can use this form any other location like this:

```
MyForm.Current.DoSomething();
```

Of course this will only work if you've already opened an instance of MyForm.